# Is this Sequence and Series question wrong?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have spent a lot of time and effort on this question. However, the problem is that I am unable to get the answer in the format of the options. I tried using *Arithmetico Geometric Progression*, however that didn't work. So, I tried forming the general term but didn't have any success, which has led me to think that this question might even be **wrong altogether**. This question is taken from a *maths olympiad workbook*. Any help will be sincerely appreciated!

> The sum
> $$ 1 + (1+2) x + (1+2+3) x^2 + (1+2+3+4) x^3 + \cdots + (1+2+ \cdots +n) x^{n-1}$$
> is equal to

**NOTE: I am attaching a photo of the question as I do not know how to use LaTeX.**[image]

Comment: What is the answer that you got and how did you get it? Including those information helps us provide better answers. Also, *learn how to use MathJaX* since that also increases the probability of a good answer.

Comment: If the series sum is $S$ then perhaps consider $S-Sx$

Comment: It's multiple choice.  Plug in, say $2$ for $x$ and $3$ for $n$ in all 5 expressions.  Lather. Rinse. Repeat.

Comment: I'll try to learn MathJaX. I am unable to reach till the answer.

Comment: @B.Goddard - unlikely to get convergence for $|x| \ge 1$

Comment: @Henry Its a finite sum, convergence isn't an issue

Comment: I tried that but didn't work. Or maybe I did not apply that correctly. @Henry

Comment: @QC_QAOA Yes. Convergence is not an issue.

Comment: @B.Goddard That isn't how I want to solve it.

Comment: Where is the question coming from?

Comment: As I said, from a maths olympiad workbook.

Comment: @PhysicsGuy I mean which olympiad and at which level?

Comment: It is for national maths olympiad of USA/UK. Equivalent of 2-3 levels lower than IMO

Comment: It may not be a good method to solve it, but it would narrow down which answer is correct, so you could work toward that.

Comment: @Henry  It's a finite sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\displaystyle\begin{align}S&=1+(1+2)x+(1+2+3)x^2+ \ldots +(1+2+3+\ldots n)x^{n-1}\\
Sx&=\qquad \qquad + x+ \;(1+2)x^2+\ldots + (1+2+\ldots+n-1)x^{n-1} + (1+2+\ldots +n)x^n\\
\hline
S-Sx&=1+2x+3x^2+\ldots+ nx^{n-1}-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}x^n\\
(S-Sx)x&=\quad +x\;+2x^2+\ldots +(n-1)x^{n-1}+nx^n-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}x^{n+1}\\
\hline
(S-Sx)(1-x)&=1+x\;+\;x^2+\ldots +x^{n-1}-nx^n-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}(x^n-x^{n+1})\\
\implies S(1-x)^2&={1(1-x^n)\over 1-x}-nx^{n}-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}x^n(1-x)\\
\implies S&={1-x^n\over (1-x)^3}-{nx^n\over (1-x)^2}-\frac{n(n+1)}{2(1-x)}x^n\end{align}$

As simple as that.The question is not wrong. Correct answer is option (A)

Comment: @PhysicsGuy I hope you are familiar with the methods used, i.e., geometric sum. That's it

Comment: Thanks Aman bhaiya!

Answer (score 1):

This works.
$$\sum^\infty_n \left( \sum^n_ii \right) x^n$$
Edit: just saw the multiple choices. This isn't correct answer, sorry for posting.

Comment: It's not infinite

Comment: The answer is wrong my friend.

Comment: If you realise that your answer is incorrect, it is best to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

The sum is

$$\begin{aligned}
S_n(x) &= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k(k+1)}{2} x^{k-1}
\end{aligned}$$ which is the second derivative of

$$\begin{aligned}
U_n(x) &= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2} x^{k+1} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1-x^{n+2}}{1-x} -x-1\right)
\end{aligned}$$

Compute the second derivative of $U_n(x)$... and you'll get the desired $S_n(x)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, I wanted to know if there is any way which doesn't involve calculus and stuff as I am not yet familiar with derivatives etc.

Comment: @PhysicsGuy Then tell us what you're / you aren't familiar with!!!

Comment: Sorry! Didn't know that you would post an answer involving calculus.

Answer (score 1):

The sum can be written as

$$S(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n\left[\sum_{j=1}^k j\right]x^{k-1}$$

It is well known that

$$\sum_{j=1}^k=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$$

which gives us

$$S(x)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n k(k+1)x^{k-1}$$

Now, note that

$$\int\int k(k+1)x^{k-1}dx dx=x^{k+1}+Ax+B$$

for constants $A$ and $B$. Thus, integrating $S(x)$ twice gives us

$$F(x)=\int \int S(x) dx dx =A^{'}x+B^{'}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n x^{k+1}$$

(again, where $A^{'}$ and $B^{'}$ are unimportant constants). Luckily for us, this is a finite geometric series so

$$F(x)=A^{'}x+B^{'}+\frac{x^2(x^n-1)}{2(x-1)}$$

Differentiating twice gives the answer of

$$S(x)=\frac{-2 + x^n (2 + n (-1 + x) (-3 + n (-1 + x) + x))}{2 (-1 + x)^3}$$

---

EDIT: Without differentiation, define

$$S_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n\left[\sum_{j=1}^k j\right]x^{k-1}$$

We will prove by induction that

$$S_n(x)=\frac{-2 + x^n (2 + n (-1 + x) (-3 + n (-1 + x) + x))}{2 (-1 + x)^3}$$

It is clear that

$$S_1(x)=1=\frac{-2 + x^1 (2 + 1 (-1 + x) (-3 + 1 (-1 + x) + x))}{2 (-1 + x)^3}$$

(well, maybe not clear but this step is more or less just simplifying). Now, assume that for some $n\geq 1$ we have

$$S_n(x)=\frac{-2 + x^n (2 + n (-1 + x) (-3 + n (-1 + x) + x))}{2 (-1 + x)^3}$$

Then

$$S_{n+1}(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\left[\sum_{j=1}^k j\right]x^{k-1}=x^n\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}j+\sum_{k=1}^n\left[\sum_{j=1}^k j\right]x^{k-1}=x^n\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}j+S_n(x)$$

At this point, you would use the fact that

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}$$

and then simplify the overall sum to complete the induction step.

Comment: I am not yet familiar with calculus. Is there any way not involving differentiation and stuff?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Upvoted.

Comment: Added a non-differentiation way of doing it but its a little bit of a cheat. I used my answer from the differentiation section and then proved by induction that this was indeed the answer. Technically, it is indeed a proof without differentiation.

Answer (score 1):

$$\displaystyle \begin{align*}1+(1+2)x+...(1+2+3+...+n)x^{n-1}&=\sum_{p=1}^n\bigg(p\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}x^k\bigg) 
\\&=\sum_{p=1}^n\frac{p(x^p-1)}{x-1}
\\&=\frac{1}{x-1}\bigg(\sum_{p=1}^n{px^p}-n\bigg) \end{align*}$$
Define $\displaystyle T_n=\sum_{p=1}^n{px^p}$. Note that $xT_n-T_n=x^{n+1}-(x+x^2+x^3+...+x^n)$.
Now you can easily compute $T_n$ and hence the original summation.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try. This is what I was looking for.